# How to enable jQuery, Bootstrap code assist in Spring tools Suite

Tags: jquery, spring-boot, bootstrap-4, eclipse-plugin, spring-tool-suite

I want to know if there's any plugin or any sort of ways to add content assist/ auto complete for jQuery and Bootstrap codes when I'm writing it in STS4.

Comment: Since Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse is a regular Eclipse distribution and built on top of Eclipse, you can install regular Eclipse extensions and plugins into it. I haven't used specific extensions for jQuery or Bootstrap yet, but I am sure they exist.

Comment: Yes they exist and I know It's eclipse only, I just want to know the names of the best ones.

Comment: Ah, okay, I see. Since I haven't used them myself, I can't really recommend one specifically. Maybe someone else here?